# cannot set property of inner html

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

For some reason whenever I load the page it tells me that it can't set the property of innerHTML. I tried everything that everyone else was saying but to no avail. I tried adding a window.onload, and I tried moving my script tags to allow time for the DOM to load, but it still doesn't work. What should I do?

```
<!-- The Canvas of which the buttons and labels will be placed on -->
    <canvas id="myCanvasUI" width="100" height="400" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"> </canvas>


<!-- Left and Right Arrows to modify the values of the Enzymes Variable -->
    <button class="buttonsEnzyme buttonsLeft" style="background: url(LeftArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="myEnzymesMinus()"></button>
        <p id="myEnzymesPara"> <b> ENZYMES </b> </p>
            <button class="buttonsEnzyme buttonsRight" style="background: url(RightArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="myEnzymesPlus()"></button>
                <p id="myEnzymesValue"></p>

<!-- Left and Right Arrows to modify the values of the Substrates Variable -->
    <button class="buttonsSubstrates buttonsLeft" style="background: url(LeftArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="mySubstratesMinus()"></button>
        <p id="mySubstratesPara"> <b> SUBSTRATES </b> </p>
            <button class="buttonsSubstrates buttonsRight" style="background: url(RightArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="mySubstratesPlus()"></button> 

<!-- Left and Right Arrows to modify the values of the Inhibitors Variable -->
    <button class="buttonsInhibitors buttonsLeft" style="background: url(LeftArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="myInhibitorsMinus()"></button>
        <p id="myInhibitorsPara"> <b> INHIBITORS </b> </p>
            <button class="buttonsInhibitors buttonsRight" style="background: url(RightArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="myInhibitorsPlus()"></button>

<!-- Left and Right Arrows to modify the values of the Temperature Variable -->
    <button class="buttonsTemperature buttonsLeft" style="background: url(LeftArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="myTemperatureMinus()"></button>
        <p id="myTemperaturePara"> <b> TEMPERATURE </b> </p>
            <button class="buttonsTemperature buttonsRight" style="background: url(RightArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="myTemperaturePlus()"></button>
                                        </div>

<!-- The Canvas of which the model will be placed on -->
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"> </canvas>
        <canvas id="myModel" width="390" height="390" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"> </canvas>


<script>
var enzymes = 1;
var substrates = 20;
var inhibitors = 0;
var temperature = 25;
var container = 400;
var pH = 7;

function myEnzymesMinus() {
    enzymes -= 1;
    console.log(enzymes);
    }

function myEnzymesPlus() {
    enzymes += 1;
    console.log(enzymes);
    }

window.onload = function displayEnzyme() {
    document.getElementById(myEnzymesValue).innerHTML = enzymes;
    }

function mySubstratesMinus() {
    substrates -= 1;
    console.log(substrates);
    }

function mySubstratesPlus() {
    substrates += 1;
    console.log(substrates);
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You never set `myEnzymesValue` so your element will be undefined - which has no innerHTML property which is why you cannot set it.  If it's not a variable, it needs quotes around it: 
`document.getElementById('myEnzymesValue').innerHTML = enzymes;`

Comment: You should use myEnzymesValue in quotes like this 'myEnzymesValue' in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just forgot to wrap in quotes your selector:

```
window.onload = function displayEnzyme() {
  document.getElementById('myEnzymesValue').innerHTML = enzymes;
}
```

You don't need `window.onload` by the way. Placing your scripts at the bottom is enough.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take `myEnzymesValue` in quote marks, otherwise JS interpreter will treat it as undecalred variable of `undefined` value

```html
<!-- The Canvas of which the buttons and labels will be placed on -->
    <canvas id="myCanvasUI" width="100" height="400" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"> </canvas>


<!-- Left and Right Arrows to modify the values of the Enzymes Variable -->
    <button class="buttonsEnzyme buttonsLeft" style="background: url(LeftArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="myEnzymesMinus()"></button>
        <p id="myEnzymesPara"> <b> ENZYMES </b> </p>
            <button class="buttonsEnzyme buttonsRight" style="background: url(RightArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="myEnzymesPlus()"></button>
                <p id="myEnzymesValue"></p>

<!-- Left and Right Arrows to modify the values of the Substrates Variable -->
    <button class="buttonsSubstrates buttonsLeft" style="background: url(LeftArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="mySubstratesMinus()"></button>
        <p id="mySubstratesPara"> <b> SUBSTRATES </b> </p>
            <button class="buttonsSubstrates buttonsRight" style="background: url(RightArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="mySubstratesPlus()"></button> 

<!-- Left and Right Arrows to modify the values of the Inhibitors Variable -->
    <button class="buttonsInhibitors buttonsLeft" style="background: url(LeftArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="myInhibitorsMinus()"></button>
        <p id="myInhibitorsPara"> <b> INHIBITORS </b> </p>
            <button class="buttonsInhibitors buttonsRight" style="background: url(RightArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="myInhibitorsPlus()"></button>

<!-- Left and Right Arrows to modify the values of the Temperature Variable -->
    <button class="buttonsTemperature buttonsLeft" style="background: url(LeftArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="myTemperatureMinus()"></button>
        <p id="myTemperaturePara"> <b> TEMPERATURE </b> </p>
            <button class="buttonsTemperature buttonsRight" style="background: url(RightArrow.png)" type="button" onclick="myTemperaturePlus()"></button>
                                        </div>

<!-- The Canvas of which the model will be placed on -->
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"> </canvas>
        <canvas id="myModel" width="390" height="390" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"> </canvas>


<script>
var enzymes = 1;
var substrates = 20;
var inhibitors = 0;
var temperature = 25;
var container = 400;
var pH = 7;

function myEnzymesMinus() {
    enzymes -= 1;
    console.log(enzymes);
    }

function myEnzymesPlus() {
    enzymes += 1;
    console.log(enzymes);
    }

window.onload = function displayEnzyme() {
    document.getElementById('myEnzymesValue').innerHTML = enzymes;
    }

function mySubstratesMinus() {
    substrates -= 1;
    console.log(substrates);
    }

function mySubstratesPlus() {
    substrates += 1;
    console.log(substrates);
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing double quotes here in the document.getElementById function and that is the reason it is not able to get that DOM element.
You have to enclose the element id in double quotes.

`document.getElementById("myEnzymesValue").innerHTML = enzymes;`